# How to access nested json value in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I can access

```
{
  "customersId": 30,
  "name": null,
  "phoneNo": "tea",
  "gender": 0,
  "relation": 0,
  "createdBy": null,
  "doB": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
  "password": "123456",
  "thumb": null,
  "motherTounge": null
}
```

these values as `{{User.customersId}}`

But how can I access

```
"familydata":{"familyData":1,"familyName":"xyz","familyDescription":"xyz","pincode":"xyz","customersId":30}
```

from below JSON result

```
{
  "customersId": 30,
  "name": null,
  "phoneNo": "tea",
  "gender": 0,
  "relation": 0,
  "createdBy": null,
  "doB": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
  "password": "123456",
  "thumb": null,
  "motherTounge": null,
  "familydata": {
    "familyData": 1,
    "familyName": "xyz",
    "familyDescription": "xyz",
    "pincode": "xyz",
    "customersId": 30
  }
}
```

**user.service.ts**

```
getUser(phoneno: string): Observable<User> {
    this.usersUrl =this.usersUrl+'Customers/GetCustomersData'
    const url = `${this.usersUrl}/${phoneno}`+'?includeAll=true';
    return this.http.get<User>(url)
      .pipe(
      map(data => new User().deserialize(data)),
       tap( data => console.log('getCustomer: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),

        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
```

In User Component

```
this.userService.getUser(this.phoneno).subscribe({
      next: user => this.user = user,
      error: err => this.errorMessage = err
    });
```

in User model

```
thumb :string;
motherTounge :string;
familyData : familydata
```

Comment: add your code about how you access first json.

Comment: Vimal,  did u try `{{User.familydata}}` ??

Comment: @ShashankVivek [object Object]

Comment: @Vimal: whats the code in `User().deserialize(data)` ??

Comment: deserialize(input: any): this {
   
      Object.assign(this, input);
  
   
      this.familyData = input.familyData.map(familyData => new familydata().deserialize(familyData ));
  
      return this;
    } i followed https://nehalist.io/angular-7-models/